# Refactor class to avoid writing same pattern in every method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, try-catch, using

I have a class with a lot of static methods for managing database operations. All methods follow this pattern:

```
try
{
   using(var trans = new TransactionScope())
   {
      using(var context = new DBContext())
      {
         . . . // method body
      }
      trans.Complete();
   }
}
catch(Excepcion ex)
{
   Log.Error(ex.Message);
   if (ex.InnerException != null)
      Log.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
}
```

How can I refactor my code so that it is not needed to write this structure in every method?

EDIT for implementing Jon's response.

```
public static T TransactionalOperation<T>(Func<DBContext, T> databaseAction)
{
   T retVal = default(T);
   try
   {
      using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
      {
         using (var context = new DBContext())
         {
            if (databaseAction != null)
               retVal = databaseAction(context);
         }
         trans.Complete();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Log.Error(ex.ToString());
   }
   return retVal;
}
public static void TransactionalOperation(Action<DBContext> databaseAction)
{
   TransactionalOperation(context =>
      {
         databaseAction(context);
         return string.Empty;
      });
}
```

And used like this:

```
public static string GetUserLanguage(string owner)
{
   return
      TransactionalOperator(context => context.clients.Single(c => c.Id == owner).Language);
}
```

Comment: FYI - `ex.ToString()` is **much** more useful than just `ex.Message`.

Comment: You're looking for template method pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you should pass "method body" in as a delegate:

```
public void GiveMeAProperName(Action<DBContext> databaseAction)
{
    try
    {
       using(var trans = new TransactionScope())
       {
          using(var context = new DBContext())
          {
             . . . // method body
          }
          trans.Complete();
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       Log.Error(ex.Message);
       if (ex.InnerException != null)
          Log.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
GiveMeAProperName(context =>
{
    // Do stuff with your context here
});
```

As noted in comments, you might want to have an overload of:

```
public void GiveMeAProperName<T>(Func<DBContext, T> databaseAction)
```

so that you can return a value. You can easily write your `Action` overload to just delegate to that:

```
public void GiveMeAProperName(Action<DBContext> databaseAction)
{
    GiveMeAProperName(context =>
    {
        databaseAction(context);
        return "ignored";
    }
}
```

I would strongly advise different exception handling though:

- You're *only* logging the message. Why do you think the stack trace is unimportant? Just log the whole exception - that will include nested exceptions etc
- You're effectively ignoring the failure afterwards. I'd personally rip out the try/catch entirely, in most cases... catch exceptions at a very high level, not at the level of doing database operations.

Comment: Might be better with a `Func<Context, T>`? Some operations may want data returned?

Comment: @RobH: Possibly - will add that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, would you mind to revise my edited question where I've tried to implement your response. In particular the IDE didn't let me write the Action overload by calling the delegate parameterless as you suggested.

Comment: @JPG: "didn't let me" doesn't give me any idea of what went wrong... *Always* give the full error message. (Additionally, there's not really much point in adding the solution into the question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The error is in databaseAction(): "Delegate 'Action' does not take 0 arguments". Regarding editing my question with the solution I did it because I'm not sure if my understanding of it is fully correct.

Comment: @JPG: Ah, right - edited my answer. The lambda expression needs to take a `context` and pass it through. But yes, other than that (and that I still don't like this way of "handling" exceptions by pretending they didn't happen) it looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

Create static method :

```
public static void UsingDBContext(Action<DBContext> action){
try
    {
       using(var trans = new TransactionScope())
       {
          using(var context = new DBContext())
          {
             action(context);
          }
          trans.Complete();
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       Log.Error(ex.Message);
       if (ex.InnerException != null)
          Log.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
UsingDbContext( con => {
  ..\\ write your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generic method that has that wrapper and calls a delegate that you provide:

```
private static T Call<T>(Func<DbContext, T> func) {
  T result = null;
  try {
    using(var trans = new TransactionScope()) {
      using(var context = new DBContext()) {
         result = func(context);
      }
      trans.Complete();
   }
  } catch(Excepcion ex) {
    Log.Error(ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null) {
      Log.Error(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<int> someValues = Call(context => {
  // some code that uses context and returns a list of ints
});
```

As the return type is generic, you can have it return any type that you want. It can even be an anonymous type.

You should however consider rethrowing the exception in the method. Right now it will just return `null` when there is an error, rethrowing the exception gives the calling method more information on what it was that went wrong.